# W3C validator: "Element head is missing a required instance of child element title"

Tags: php, html, w3c-validation

I'm trying to validate my document for HTML5 using the W3C validator at http://validator.w3.org/check. When I run the code below using "direct input" I get error messages like *Element head is missing a required instance of child element title* and *Stray start tag html*. This baffles me, because the `<html>` tag is right there. Why can't the validator see it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="some content">
<title>page title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using PHP to generate parts of the file.

Comment: It looks fine to me when I copy paste your snippet into the direct input. Are you uploading a file / Validate by URI?

Comment: Both. Turns out I had invisible characters in my code which upset the validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I viewed it in a hex editor I discovered two null bytes (hex code 0x00) before the `<html>` tag exactly where my first `<?php ?>` tag was. When I copied the code or ran it by URL, the validator encountered the null bytes. When I wrote the code manually, it validated fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
/* the PHP tag apparently outputs two null bytes */
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>page title</title>
</head>
<body>page body</body>
</html>
```

I moved the first PHP tag down to the first line of the body and the validation passed.

Comment: thanks, there were several of them. Notepad++ Hex Editor helped me to figure it out.

Comment: Update: sometimes the PHP tag needs to be first in the file, to send headers for example. In that case, make sure you're using a proper character set. UTF-8 with and without BOM "byte order marker" may be treated differently.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

it is not giving error, instead of two warnings, i have checked in the same link.

Comment: You are technically correct. The reason I failed validating the text was that I had copy-pasted some invisible characters (null bytes) that upset the validator.