# PHP seems to output HTML code incorrectly and with hidden characters

Tags: php, html, validation

I have a php page. The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <?php include("some_file.php"); ?>
    <title>Calculadora dos Custos do Automóvel</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>aaa</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see nothing is wrong.

Though, view source of Firefox gives red erros and w3 validator gives also errors.

[image]

I'm around this for two days, and it is so strange. I suppose it has to do with some strange characters php might be inputting into the HTML code but I'm not sure. Or perhaps the encoding considering that the code has Portuguese characters.

Comment: Do you have anything else in the page?

Comment: It's something strange with the white space before `<title>` in your `<head>`. If I remove the white space when validating on w3 all is good. If I replace your space with spaces from my keyboard also everything is ok. So should be ok to be space there. I really don't know what is wrong with that white space... Try to remove the space before title and add again. Or copy and paste the white space that you use before `<meta>` tags.

Comment: Probably the same problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394972/w3c-validator-element-head-is-missing-a-required-instance-of-child-element-tit

Comment: @DanielDudas, thank you so much, is there a way to detect such BOM in Notepad++ or do you think it was created by some problem with the php? How can I detect such hidden characters? I use UTF-8 in Notepad++

Comment: @Blinkydamo, my code just runs some php functions which do not echo anything. `<? include("./country files/country_list.php"); ?>
    <? include("./php/country_selector.php"); ?>
    <? include('./php/favicon_selector.php'); ?>
    <? include('./php/css_embed.php'); ?>
    <title><? echo $WEB_PAGE_TITLE ?></title>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said BOMs are a problem when including PHP files, even if those files do not echo anything

### PHP includes

> At the time this article was written, if you include some external
>   file in a page using PHP and that file starts with a BOM, it may
>   create blank lines.
>
> This is because the BOM is not stripped before inclusion into the
>   page, and acts like a character occupying a line of text.
>
> **You should ensure that the included files do not start with a BOM.**

in: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark

### Detecting BOMs

You can online detect BOMs *within the content* of your HTML page using the [W3C Internationalization Checker](https://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/)

Answer (score 1):

There are two [BOMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) just before the `<title>` tag. Remove them (e.g. delete everything between the second `<meta>` and the `<title>`) and everything should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so very much Jiri. Is there a way to detect such BOM or hidden chars in Notepad++ or do you think it was created by some problem with the php? I use UTF-8 in Notepad++ and I go to `View->Show Symbol->Show All Characters` and I see nothing. My php functions just run some code which do not echo enything.

Comment: @Aónio: see [this superuser thread](http://superuser.com/questions/680291/notepad-visibility-for-bom)

Comment: Notepad++ 

Encoding > Encode in UTF-8

not

Encoding > Encode in UTF-8-BOM

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here you are using Notepad++ and we already cleared that the problem is because of BOM of the php files that you include before `title`.

To solve this for each file that you use open in Notepad++ and from menu choose `Encoding` -> `Encode in UTF-8 without BOM` and save the file. Do this for all your files in the probject (php files).

You should not have anymore that special characters in front of title.

Also make sure you start the `<?php` tag at the beginning of the file (no white spaces or new lines before) and if the file contains only php you don't have to use closing `?>` tag. This way you are sure that you will not have spaces at the end of the file.

Answer (score -1):

There is something before

```
<title>
```

remove everything before title tag

Comment: Doesn't look like you need to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19510239/2233391

Answer (score -1):

try to save your file with UTF-8 encoding

Answer (score -1):

You certainly have a problem with the white space before  in your  tag. Please rewrite your code afresh using your replacing the spaces with spaces from your keyboard.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            <title>Calculadora dos Custos do Automóvel</title>      
    </head>
    <body>  
        <p>aaa</p>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way to detect such BOM or hidden chars in Notepad++ or do you think it was created by some problem with the php? I use UTF-8 in Notepad++ and I go to `View->Show Symbol->Show All Characters` and I see nothing. My php functions just run some code which do not echo enything.

Comment: I dont have any in mind at the moment but you can always recheck your code from time to time using validation tools online as you have seen in what others have adviced you. Now if my answer worked for you mark it as correct